# Ubuntu 64 bit 16.04 LTS keeps freezing on laptop Hp Pavilion X2

Tags: 16.04, 64-bit, freeze

The machine keeps freezing, mainly when using the Chromium or the OpenOffice. But it is random. When it freezes, the terminal is not accessible neither the tty terminal using CTRL+ALT+ Fx. The machine simply stops responding. 
I checked some of the suggestions mentioned here: [Tools to diagnose Ubuntu problems](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75325/tools-to-diagnose-ubuntu-problems?s=2%7C0.5908) but i did not found any problems. I formated the hard disk and install the 16.04 64 bits ubuntu and all the updates but the problem keeps occuring. 
The user is feed up and ands to return to windows but i want to give a try but this kind of problems does not happens in any of my computers. Can anyone help me to find the problems for this mistery? Thank you.

Comment: How much RAM do you have? How much SWAP?

Comment: free -m 
Mem 3781
Swap 3922

Comment: I just installed psensor with logging activated to see if it is a temperature problem that freezes the machine. Until now... nothing.

Comment: It seems you have enough RAM... Try to monitor the usage of the system with `top` (open a terminal and stick it to the front, right click on title>always on top) and monitor the CPU/RAM usage when the system freezes.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it isn't a hardware problem? Your syslogs aren't turning up any errors(did you check them all?), that makes me think it might not be a OS problem.

You can check your memory with memtest86, https://help.ubuntu.com/16.04/ubuntu-help/disk-check.html for your hard drive.(or use UBCD or something like it to test your system).

You could test to see if the problem occurs in windows. it will at least help you exclude some things.

Comment: i can use grub2 for the memtest86+. It is installed but never shows in grub2. This https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2 did not helped.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/126160/how-can-i-add-the-memtest86-options-back-to-the-grub-menu

Comment: i follow that and the file 20-memtest... was there but still did not show in grub2.

Comment: You also ran the update-grub? Do you still have the live usb/cd? this also contains memtest. here is someone that recommends grub customiser: http://askubuntu.com/questions/312304/memtest86-options-are-missing-in-grub-menu

Answer (score 0):

I found that upgrading to the 4.6.5 kernel (http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.6.5/) helps a lot - no freezing at this level.

At 4.7.x and later releases, there are some improvements (battery status indicator works) but the freezing returns. Also try the most recent kernel releases as Cherry Trail support seems to be improving little by little.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue with my two HP pc: pavillion and Elitebook 8450P
the issue was due to the graphic card driver ...
On HP Elitebook 8450P shifting into the open source instead of Nvidia driver solved the issue
On both cases I used other drivers option to change driver and solve the issue

You may consider this option as one possible solution